# Is the <firebase-login> element available in Polymer 1.0?

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0, firebase-authentication, google-web-component

Is the `<firebase-login>` element available in Polymer 1.0?

[The documentation here](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/firebase-element?active=firebase-auth) for the `<firebase-element>` makes no mention of the `<firebase-login>` element. However it does mention `<firebase-auth>`.

On the other hand, my [Polymer Starter Kit](https://github.com/polymerelements/polymer-starter-kit) (PSK) ships the `<firebase-login>` element.

Which is the correct element to use? Do I need to update my PSK?

What's going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `<firebase-auth>.`

- [Github Demo](https://github.com/GoogleWebComponents/firebase-element/blob/master/demo/x-login.html)
- [Documentation](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/firebase-element?active=firebase-auth)